# Deep learning in medicine(Articles)

Tags: deep-learning, biostatistics

I am looking for the articles in Medicine, where deep learning techniques were applied. I googled but I found only tutorials.

Maybe you can provide me good articles?

Comment: Perhaps  in medicine people call it as biostatistics not machine learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clinical prediction, Jimeng Sun's lab at Georgia Tech (http://sunlab.org/publication) is a good example.  They were pretty much the first to use RNNs for predicting, for example, heart failure.  Also, there are other good examples like Joseph Futoma, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.05894.pdf.

For phenotyping, researchers such as Lipton have applied various deep learning algorithms.

For both, see conferences like http://mucmd.org.  Other researchers include Michaela Van Der Shaar or P. Svolovitz for example.

For imaging, the radiology/ pathology/ dermatology/ ophthalmology communities have become very interested in CNNs. Generally many large imaging conferences (CVPR) have a few papers on medical image processing applications. Some like MICCAI are specialized for it, and now conferences like RNSA have entire section devoted to AI.